# Workflow with reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4

I'm trying to dynamically update cells in a `UITableView`. The events are triggered by data received by background threads, so everything is asynchronous and it's impossible to predict the order of the events.

I'm not sure what the workflow is supposed to be in this case. How can I make sure that the row count and indexpath are correct when calling `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation`? There could still be an animation going on by a previous call to `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation`.

If all the changes happen at the same time, I can use `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`, but what do I do in the above situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hanno, I recommend using a command object model to queue the changes on the main thread.

Here's how:

- On the callback in the main thread, append the add or delete as an object to a queue (mutable array).
- Walk the queue to add and remove objects on the main thread, with each operation being atomic (i.e gets the table status first, processes it without interruption, removes the head of the queue)
- Decide if you want to interrupt the animation if there are more commands on the queue, or wait for the animation to end then process the next queued object.

A mix of a timer and animationDidFinish callbacks should do it.

Comment: Why does it have to be so complicated :-( It turns out that for my case a call to both `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` is enough as it forces to tableView to reload the cell geometry.

Answer (score 0):

Since you would have to do all the table updates in the main thread anyway (because UIKit has to be called on the main thread), I don't see a concurrency problem here. Whenever you receive new data, call a method on the main thread that updates the table. This method will block the main thread until it has finished. This should make sure that the table view retains its integrity.

Or are you concerned about overlapping row animations?

Comment: I'm performing all the UIKit stuff on the main thread. But when an animation is going on that removes a cell and I want to update another one, the row counts/indexpaths are getting mixed up.